# Could not find developer disk image, xcode 7.3, El Capitan, 10.11.4

Tags: ios, xcode

I know this question has been asked ad nauseam however in all the answers it speaks about updating your xcode or el capitan, however both of mine are fully updated and I am still getting the error Could not find developer disk image.

Also I just realised that if i click about xcode about it says I am version 7.2 but in my app store it says I have xcode 7.3, this is likely my problem

Thanks for any help.

Comment: as you saying, XCode and Mac OS are upto date, then try after deleting the previous version of XCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not updated yet it may be in downloading status. so after it dowloaded the problem will be rectified once it is reopened.

Comment: Thanks the solution was pretty simple, just a restart of my computer, your answer was pretty much on track.